# MariaDB, Anyway to truncate * results?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Are there any tricks for truncating each column's output when selecting all from a table?

```
SELECT * FROM table_name;
```

Something similar to this in concept?

```
SELECT SUBSTR(*, 1, 10) FROM table_name;
```

Comment: Sounds like the XY problem. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Concat the columns and truncate it

Comment: I think everyone is missing the intent of the question, obviously i know how to list out all of the columns with substr() since i mention it in my question. I just wanted to know if there was a trick, short cut, to quickly show a "snapshot" truncated table that would fit my screen cleanly without having to type out a dozen column names or use \G. So the answer is "No, there isn't a way." Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it for individual column

```
SELECT SUBSTR(colname1, pos, len), SUBSTR(colname2, pos, len) FROM tablename;
```

Comment: you can also concat them and then substring it.

Comment: Typing out all of the columns by name wouldn't be selecting all (SELECT *).

Answer (score 0):

The `*` wildcard just selects all columns, without any modification. It does not support use inside expressions.

To do what you describe, you would have to spell out all your columns by name:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(CONCAT(col1, col2, col3, ...), 1, 10) FROM table_name;
```

Comment: That's true. You didn't describe what you wanted the query to do. You should show an example of a hypothetical row of data, and what you want the result of your query to be. Please edit your question above to add that

Comment: You are right, i can see how the way it was worded could be interpreted that way. Thanks for the input.